# Simple Intellij Kotlin project doesn't recognize LinkedHashMap or other collections

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, java-8

I installed the latest version of Intellij on Linux (2019.2.3 Community Edition) and added the Kotlin plugin.

I followed the Kotlin website's [Getting Started with IntelliJ IDEA](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started.html) and created a hello world app. It worked fine until I added a LinkedHashMap. (BTW, I was running into this in a bigger project, but simplified it to this.)

This is all the code I added:

```
import kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    println("Hello world")
    val map: LinkedHashMap<Int, String> = linkedMapOf(1 to "x", 2 to "y", -1 to "zz")
    println(map) 

}
```

I get this error on the map line:

```
Cannot access class 'java.util.LinkedHashMap'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.
```

You can see I have 1.8 selected in the modules, and I verified java 8 is installed via terminal (`java -version`). What is the issue for this vanilla/default installation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. For some reason, if I change the module to 11 (java 11) from 1.8 it just works.

[image]

Kind of weird that standard collections don't work out of the box, but... eh, I guess this works.